# I want to dissociate lists in a data frame into single values to different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a database that goes like that:

```
d <- c(01, 02, 03, 04)
h <- c("19:00", "19:00", "07:00", "07:00")
p1 <- c(123, 321, 123, 123)
p2 <- c(321, 345, 567, 567)

df <- data.frame(date = d, hours = h, person1 = p1, person2 = p2)
```

I used this code to associate all the characteristics of each person1 in different columns:

EDITED: `rn = rowid(person1, date, hours)` is the actual code. Not `rn = rowid(person1)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(rn = rowid(person1, date, hours)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(date, hours, person2),
              names_sep="")
```

But this code gives me this output:

```
# person1    date1        hours1                            person21

# 123        c(1,3,4)     c("19:00", "07:00", "07:00")      c(321,567,567)

# 321        2            19:00                             345
```

I Dont want it to repeat values like `07:00` or `567`. I want it to give me each different value in different columns, ignoring repeated values. And if possible, organized like that:

```
# person1 date1  date2 date3  date4...  hours1  hours2 ... person21  person22   person23   person24

# 123     01     NA    03     04        07:00   19:00      NA        321        NA         567

# 321     NA     02    NA     NA        NA      19:00      NA        NA         345        NA
```

person21, 22, 23 and 24 being the first, second, third, fourth, and so on person of my `df1$person1`.

But the ideal output for me would be something like this:

```
# person1 d01  d02  d03  d04 ...  h07:00  h19:00 ... p123  p321   p345  p567

# 123     1    0    1    1   ...  1       0      ... 1      0     0     1

# 321     0    1    0    0   ...  0       0      ... 1      0     0     1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The code is not giving a list for me

Comment: @akrun I edited it the right way now. The right code actually is the second suggestion you gave me in the older post.

Comment: In the last code block, you mentioned `ideal output`.  I was trying to get that output in the solution below

Comment: Ah, ok. the code is almost what I want. I just want it to not register repeated values. You can see better what is happening using the code I edited where I put ````mutate(rn = rowid(person1, date, hours))````  intead of  ``mutate(rn = rowid(person1))``, as you suggested in my yesterday post. It gives me those ``c("19:00", "07:00", "07:00")``     ``c(321,567,567)`` lists.

Comment: I updated the solution below.  It looks like your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to return a binary output, specify the `values_fn` and `values_fill` in `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
 mutate(rn = rowid(person1)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(date, hours, person2),
        names_sep="", values_fn = length, values_fill = list(date = 0, hours = 0, person2 = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 10
#   person1 date1 date2 date3 hours1 hours2 hours3 person21 person22 person23
#     <dbl> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1     123     1     1     1      1      1      1        1        1        1
#2     321     1     0     0      1      0      0        1        0        0
```

---

If we want the values to be also column names, an option is to reshape into 'long' format first and then do the `pivot_wider` after transformation

```
df %>% 
   mutate(date = sprintf("%02d", date)) %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -person1) %>% 
   mutate(name = substr(name, 1, 1)) %>% 
   unite(name, name, value, sep="") %>% 
   distinct(person1, name) %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from =n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 10
#  person1   d01 `h19:00`  p321   d02  p345   d03 `h07:00`  p567   d04
#  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 123         1        1     1     0     0     1        1     1     1
#2 321         0        1     0     1     1     0        0     0     0
```

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to automatically change the colnames to the equivalent values in the table? Like, instead of ``hours1``, I wanted it to be ``07:00``. Its because the numer of columns is gigantic and I would take a life time to edit it one by one

Comment: @ApoloReis updated the solution. Can you check now. thanks

Comment: It works perfectly!!! I just had to change ``%02d`` for ``%02s`` in the original table or it would return me the error ````Erro: Problem with `mutate()` input `Data`.
x formato inválido'%02d'; use o formato %s para objetos caractere
i Input `Data` is `sprintf("%02d", Data)`.````. I dont think its going to be a problem with the original table, right? Thank you so much! @akrun

Comment: @ApoloReis that could be because your 'date' is string in original dataset and here it is integer